# autocomplete does not work for php variables without dollar sign in Vscode

Tags: php, visual-studio-code

I define a variable like

```
$name = 'Komail';
```

In PhpStorm , when I type name without dollar sign , PhpStorm show `$name` in autocomplete box and simply I can enter on it. 
Has Vscode setting for this option?

Answer (score 0):

I found PHP Tools extension that adds local variables without dollar to the autocomplete. It works well, but the problem is the local variables don't come to the top, and searching for them is sometimes more headache than just typing a $.